# ayuda para manipular un ngValue

Tags: angularjs

Yo tengo un elemento donde quiero mandar la puntuación completa por el value, pero en caso de pasar la fecha correspondiente quiero mandar la mitad de la puntuación, como tengo que hacer? por favor y gracias

```
<input  type="checkbox" name="puntuacion.puntos" ng-value="@{{actividad.puntuacion}}">
```

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, podrías agregar todo el código pertinente y el tipo de error? Para que sea mas fácil brindarte ayuda, te recomendaría que mires esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.

Comment: lo que describí es lo que quiero hacer pero no logro como :/ por eso pido ayuda :(

Comment: Cuando capturas lo que tiene el `value` que te arroja?